# How to resume multipart uploads after application restart using TransferManager?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying write an application to continuously upload large data (multipart uploads) to Amazon's S3 Storage. However, my application needs to be able to shut down mid-transfer and pick up from where it left off the next time it's restarted.

From playing around a little bit with the C++ SDK, the TransferManager class provides a `RetryUpload` function that requires a shared pointer to the `TransferHandle` object that is returned upon issuing an initial `UploadFile` call. However, the transfer handle object will no longer be in existence if the application crashes or has to shut down mid-operation.

In such a case, is it possible to resume a multipart upload using the `TransferManager` class? In effect, this probably requires the reconstruction of the transfer handle object, which I am not quite sure how to do. It seems that the `TransferManager` class is just a nice wrapper around the `S3Client`, which seems to be more clearer on how to resume the operation but also seems to be more painful to use for general multipart uploading